# Couch authentication. New react native project

Tags: security, react-native, authentication, couchdb, credentials

I'm starting up a new project using Couch DB and a react native front end. I was wondering what is the recommended way of doing user authentication. weather it is setting up users in Couch DB or going through, for example, a node server to process user credentials and get a token for them and whatnot. or if there are any other ideas, I'd greatly appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CouchDB authentication system is a bit limited:

- You can't revoke sessions
- It somehow hard to integrate third party authentication (facebook, google+)
- Password recovery/reset is not available by default

Since you're building a client application, you can't implement password recovery on the client side. You'll need a backend service that handle this.

It all depends on your need. You can easily start with CouchDB's auth system and add a auth service on top of CouchDB later.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking like to us. We've decided to go with an express server that will handle the authentication side of things so we could do other kinds of third party authentication. We'll see how that works out for us.